# Using excel to count occurrences of a digit in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a long excel list of numbers.
Ultimately I need to output a sum of each integer in that list.

Example for one number...

Column A (number)=1213003

Column B (count integer 0)=2

Column C (count integer 1)=2

Column D (count integer 2)=1

Column E (count integer 3)=2

Etc up to integer 9

Makes sense...Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

---

Excel O365, formula in `B2`:

```
=LEN($A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2,SEQUENCE(1,10)-1,""))
```

<sup>You could swap `SEQUENCE(10)-1` for `ROW(1:10)-1`</sup>

---

Older versions of Excel, formula in `B2`:

```
=LEN($A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2,B$1,""))
```

Drag right and down if need be.

<sup>**Note:** If your headers are not actually integers you could use `=LEN($A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$2,COLUMN()-2,""))` in `B2` and drag right and down.</sup>

---

***EDIT**:* Just for fun, but if you want to avoid spilling out zero values but just want to count integers that are actually in your number, you could use:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER("Count  "&ROW(1:10)-1&": "&LEN($A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2,ROW(1:10)-1,"")),LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2,ROW(1:10)-1,""))<LEN($A2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Was just writing up the exact same answer. :)

Comment: Is there any advantage in using the newer version?

Comment: @OverflowStacker, it spills the resulting array =)

Comment: That was a fast answer! But you have to provide the number of cells in sequence?

Comment: The point of using `SEQUENCE` (or `ROW` for that matter) is to feed the formula an array of all 10 possible integers to substitute.

Comment: Was trying to think of a way of doing it in one formula - forgot about `SEQUENCE` and spilling.  Only found that function a couple of weeks ago.